# While com JavaScript pegando imagens dentro de uma pasta

Tags: javascript, css, materialize

Como fazer para pegar imagens dentro de uma pasta com laço de repetição em javascript e inserir juntamente com a estilização do Materialize Css

**Observanndo que as imagens dentro da pasta já estão todas com numeração sequencial.**

```
<div class="container scrollspy" id="abate">
    <h3>01 Apartamentos Cabine Elétrica</h3>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col s12 m4">
            <img src="imagens/01 Apartamentos Cabine Elétrica/1.JPG" alt="" class="responsive-img card materialboxed">
        </div>
        <div class="col s12 m4">
            <img src="imagens/01 Apartamentos Cabine Elétrica/2.JPG" alt="" class="responsive-img card materialboxed">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Vc quer inserir as imagens na div com os mesmos atributos via JavaScript?

Comment: Sim, perceba que <div class="col s12 m4"> repete a cada linha e a img tem class="responsive-img card materialboxed" que também deve repetir. entendeu ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Em vez de usar while, você poderia usar `for` e inserir o HTML na div. No `for` abaixo, o valor `10` é a quantidade de imagens que você deseja inserir:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){ // aguarda o DOM ser carregado
   // seleciona a div com a classe .row
   var container = document.querySelector("#abate > .row");
   var html = '';
   for(var x=1; x <= 10; x++){
      html += `<div class="col s12 m4">
      <img src="imagens/01 Apartamentos Cabine Elétrica/${ x }.JPG" alt="${ x }" class="responsive-img card materialboxed">
      </div>`;
   }
   
   container.innerHTML = html;
   
});
```

```html
<div class="container scrollspy" id="abate">
    <h3>01 Apartamentos Cabine Elétrica</h3>

    <div class="row">
    </div>
</div>
```